# Android How Much space is free on the SD card?

Tags: android

What is an effective way to determine how much free space is on the SD card?

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check available space on android device ? on mini sd card ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to check it yourself, here are the steps to do it:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5641/android-how-to-check-available-internal-and-sd-card-memory-space/

**UPDATE:**

I just found that there is a better SO answer to this question:

[How to Check available space on android device ? on SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods to get available space, these methods give you more control and you can get available space in different units bytes, kb, mb, gb.

[How to Check available space on android device ? on SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card/9989440#9989440)

Answer (score 0):

Usable since API level 9:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getUsableSpace();
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace%28%29)

Answer (score -2):

[Here is a function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryInfo%28android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo%29) that allows you to retrieve the amount of memory in the android device.
You can very easily find out the amount of [memory that is left of you SD card via the phones device information](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5641/android-how-to-check-available-internal-and-sd-card-memory-space/). Please elaborate if your requirements are something else.

Answer (score -5):

Create a file and write one byte at a time until you get an out of space exception.

Comment: are you really serious? a very lame answer.

Comment: Of course!  This is by far the most efficient method of determining free space.