# Get Internal Available Storage in Device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, device, space

I need to know how much internal space is left on device, but "internal" space no external SD card.

This code is used for external SD space.

[how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card)

anyone know how to get the free internal space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is [`File.getTotalSpace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace() supported in android ?

Comment: Yes. Try getFreeSpace() or getUsableSpace(). http://d.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you linked to is what you need. However, rather than:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
```

use something like:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(getFilesDir().getPath());
```