# What is the diskspace free and used in android?

Tags: android

A code/simple function that will return the available and used diskspace in the main android device.

Is making a df command and parsing it the best way? What other methods can be used?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Internal Available Storage in Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562578/get-internal-available-storage-in-device)

Comment: i tried to make a system call using df command and parsing the output. but is their any API function for this purpose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i managed to fix make a nice class.

```
// PHONE STORAGE
public static long phone_storage_free(){
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = stat.getAvailableBlocks() * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes

    return free_memory;
}

public static long phone_storage_used(){
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = (stat.getBlockCount() - stat.getAvailableBlocks()) * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes

    return free_memory;
}

public static long phone_storage_total(){
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = stat.getBlockCount() * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes

    return free_memory;
}   

// SD CARD
public static long sd_card_free(){

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = stat.getAvailableBlocks() * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes

    return free_memory;
}
public static long sd_card_used(){

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = (stat.getBlockCount() - stat.getAvailableBlocks()) * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes

    return free_memory;
}
public static long sd_card_total(){

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = stat.getBlockCount() * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes

    return free_memory;
}
```

Comment: With API >=18 `getAvailableBlocks()` and `getBlockSize()` are deprecated. Use `getAvailableBlocksLong()` and `getBlockSizeLong()` instead.

Comment: With API >= 18, you can call getAvailableBytes() directly, no hassle with the blocks and block size.