# How to calculate remaining space in local storage?

Tags: android, local-storage, space

How do I find remaining/total space on the local storage?

Can I use StatFs for this (as in - [How to Check available space on android device ? on SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can. Ran this code which seems to return the appropriate number of bytes remaining in my internal storage. Unsure about the reliability of `Environment.getDataDirectory()`

```
public static long remainingLocalStorage()
{
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    stat.restat(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    return bytesAvailable;
}
```