# Through Phone Gap how to know total size[used+unused] of Sd-card

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, sd-card

I am building multi platform Mobile Application using PhoneGap. My query is, Through LocalFileSystem how we'll know How much memory is there in Sd-Card [Used + Unused].

Or In any way possible, through any native way[android, iphone]  How we can Find the SD-Card memory information[Used + Unused].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about developing a [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) that accesses the native functionality like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card).