# Can Android notify if is running out of internal or external storage?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card, diskspace

If I'm constantly writing to a file located either in internal memory or SD card, there's a possibility that at some point there will be no more free space. This could throw an exception and create a corrupt file, depending on the way the file is written.

Can Android notify that it is running out of space, so that I can gracefully close the file?

The `ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW` intent does not work for the SD card as far as I know.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card

Comment: In my case, I am constantly writing to this file. So, I would either have to check for the available space from time to time or count how many bytes I have written. I was hopping for a system callback if it was possible. But I guess, there's no other way.

Comment: @Petrakeas   can you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to achieve this.

1) Check remaining memory in storage(there are many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5743452/519718) for this, just search), and decide if you want to create file or delete it. This is **Recommended** to check the storage before creating new files.

2) Have a subclass of Application class in your app, there is this method  named [onLowMemory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory()) which will let your application know when system is running on low memory.

Comment: I don't know the size of the file beforehand. It's increasing as time goes by. I could check the remaining size before starting to stream/write to it and count how may bytes I have written since then. 
onLowMemory() is not related to storage.

Comment: Only option seems to check size and have it in some variable and  write only based on the remaining size value.