# About Android system memory low

Tags: android

When Android occurred system memory low intent: android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW would be send
But I'm curious about

1. What's the critical value that would trigger memory low event?(How was the critical value decided?)
2. Is there a API I can use to query if current system is at memory low state?
3. When user released some memory, is there a intend would be send to notify APs that system is no longer at memory low status?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! So there is no framework API can be used? What if AP want to do someting when system become "not memory low"?(start a alarm keep monitoring? Is there a better way?)

Comment: Can I dynamically adjust the "memory low threshold" value?

Comment: fisrt one question had no answer yet><.... ;
After futher check I found the threshold is got form:
    public long getStorageLowBytes(File path) in StorageManager.java
;for those who have simlair question can reference to this API. 
But I still can't find the answer to qestion2(execpt calculating by self) & 3 ><....